# Get notified when first view controller is loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a library for iOS. I want to receive a callback in my library file when the first view controller is loaded. I tried using the following in my SDK

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(observerViewControllerChange:)
                                             name:@"UINavigationControllerDidShowViewControllerNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

But this does not seem to work when the root view controller is a tab bar controller. I need to receive  a callback in my library when the first view controller is loaded whatever the root view controller is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ideas that you can try:

1. You could use [Method swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/)

   You would need to create a category for UIViewController and replace the method viewDidLoad. Maybe you'd need to create a counter to just handle this once.
2. You could run in a separate process and wait until window.rootViewController.viewLoaded is true

Comment: Method swizzling was the one I needed